# Is LDR R0, [R2, #(7:SHL:2)] valid ARM Assembly Language Code?

Tags: assembly, arm

I came across a table of assembler operations in an introductory ARM Assembly Language book I'm reading and was wondering if:

```
LDR R0, [R2, #(7:SHL:2)]
```

is valid shorter code for the following:

```
MOV R4, #7
LDR R0, [R2, R4, LSL #2]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From an "ARM assembly language" point of view, the instruction is just `LDR R0, [R2, #28]`.

Most assemblers have some form of syntax for expressions which are evaluated at assembly time to generate immediate values. The particular assembler in this case clearly being armasm thanks to [its weird operators](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1359731181541.html) - `(7:SHL:2)` is just a less readable equivalent of `(7 << 2)`.

As @SevaAlekseyev points out, it's most likely written that way in order to make it more obvious that the offset represents 7 *words*, not just some arbitrary number of bytes, although why choose a shift over an even more obvious multiply, who knows?

Comment: It's a less readable equivalent of #(7*4). Which is to say, the 7th element of a word/pointer array at R2.